# Why " The boundary condition function BCFUN should return a column vector of length 5" error message is came?

Tags: matlab, ode

[image]

```
function Y6
solinit = bvpinit(linspace(0,1),[0;3;1;1],2);

sol = bvp4c(@ode, @bc, solinit);
y = sol.y;
time = sol.parameters*sol.x;
ut = -y(4,:);

figure(1);
plot(time,y([1 2],:)','-'); hold on;
plot(time, ut, 'k:');
axis([0 time(1,end) -1.5 3]);
text(1.3,2.5,'x_1(t)');
text(1.3,.9,'x_2(t)');
text(1.3,-.5,'u(t)');
xlabel('time');
ylabel('states');
title('Numerical solution');
hold off;

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ODE's of augmented states
function dydt = ode(t,y,T)
dydt = T*[2*y(2);4*y(4);0;-2*y(3)];

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
% boundary conditions: x1(0)=11;p2(0)=2; x2(tf)=3; 3*p1(tf)+p2(2)^2=0
function res = bc(ya,yb,T)
res = [ ya(1) - 11; ya(4); yb(2) - 3; 3*yb(3)+yb(4)^2];
```

I don't know why The boundary condition function BCFUN should return a column vector of length 5 error message is came.
Can you explain to me please? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The unknown parameters or constants, here `T`, also count as components. Thus your state has overall 4+1=5 components, requiring the setting of 5 boundary conditions.

Sometimes that is obvious, for instance in a Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue computation with the eigenvalue as parameter you want to avoid the zero solution, so demand that, e.g., the square integral has value 1.

In a ballistic shot with the flight time as parameter where you fix the location of the canon and the target as obvious boundary conditions it is not that obvious what to select as additional BC, but possibilities are to fix the initial speed or the initial angle.

---

I might be rusty, but I get from the variation of

```
L = 3*(x1(T)-9)^2 + integral(0,T, 2*u^2 +p^T*(F(x,u)-x') )
```

the saddle point conditions

```
T    : 0 = 12*x2(T)*(x1(T)-9) + 2*u(T)^2    (BC5)
x(t) : 0 = p'(t)+F_x(x,u)^T*p
       p1'(t) = -2*p2(t)                    (DE3)
       p2'(t) = 0                           (DE4)
p(t) : x'(t) = F(x,u)
       x1'(t) = 2*x2(t)                     (DE1)
       x2'(t) = 4*u(t)                      (DE2)
u(t) : 0 = 4*u + p^T*F_u(x,u)
       u(t) = -p2(t)                        (OPT)
x1(T): -p1(T)+6*(x1(T)-9)                   (BC3)
x2(0): 0 = p2(0)                            (BC4)
```

This can be directly evaluated as `p2=-u=0` (BC4+DE4+OPT) are constant, likewise `p1 = 6*(x1(T)-9)` (BC3+DE3). This in turn forces `x1(T)=9` (BC5) As now `x2(t)=3` is constant, we get `x1(t)=11+6*t`. Then the remaining expression of the functional `3*(2+6*T)^2` is minimal for `T=-1/3`. For `T=0` the minimal value of the functional is `L=12`.

Comment: Thank you so much! If i want to find U_optimal in this situation, what would i do if I use bvp4c to solve it. Can you show me how to find it please.

Comment: Variation of `tf` gives the condition `6x1'(tf)*(x1(tf)-9) + 2*u(tf)^2 = 0`. Of course, these differential conditions do not discriminate between maximum, minimum and saddle point, so you have to start close to a minimum to get the correct solution.

Comment: can you help me to find correct u(t) optimal in this problem please.? thank you so much!